# Data Mountaineer KCQL support for Json Arrays

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

i m new to kafka and i wanted to know whether KCQL queries has any support for json arrays?
I m planning to put data into influxdb
i will be getting stream of JSON arrays every second in the following format

```
[{"timestamp":"2017-10-24T12:43:39.359361982+05:30","namespace":"/intel/procfs/meminfo/high_free","data":0,"unit":"","tags":{"plugin_running_on":"AELAB110"},"version":4,"last_advertised_time":"2017-10-24T12:43:39.359519915+05:30"},{"timestamp":"2017-10-24T12:43:39.359406603+05:30","namespace":"/intel/procfs/meminfo/low_free","data":0,"unit":"","tags":{"plugin_running_on":"AELAB110"},"version":4,"last_advertised_time":"2017-10-24T12:43:39.359524142+05:30"},{"timestamp":"2017-10-24T12:43:39.359467873+05:30","namespace":"/intel/procfs/meminfo/shmem","data":35295232,"unit":"","tags":{"plugin_running_on":"AELAB110"},"version":4,"last_advertised_time":"2017-10-24T12:43:39.359526063+05:30"}]
```

and i m trying to put this json array into influxdb.... is there any way for doing this?

Comment: Do u want to put entire JSON array at a time? or is it okay to put message by message? check this http://docs.datamountaineer.com/en/latest/influx.html sink connector from Kafka to influx DB. it might helpful.

Comment: @SHAKEELMOHAMMAD hey!! i want to put one message (one Json object) at a time not the entire json array...but i m getting stream as json array. And i tried with that document it didnt help me in solving my problem, that document has shown only for one object but i m getting as json array

Comment: okay, I got it, the datamountaineer connector doesn't have that capability. you can raise the issue on GitHub.

Comment: or else, in consumer side you can get JSON array and iterate through the array and put it in the new topic as single messages and use the datamountaineer connector on that new topic. it is not the proper way. but you can or else you need to write your own connector.

Comment: What is KCQL? Do you mean KSQL by any chance?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax KCQL means Kafka Connect Query Language. which is used in datamountaineer connectors to route a particular topic data to a particular table in downstream.

Comment: @SHAKEEL MOHAMMAD...do u know any other way of doing this? Bcoz i need to finish this as soon as possible?

Comment: @SachinKademane  write a  consumer to pull messages from Kafka, you will get JSON array and iterate through the array and put each message on the new topic and use the datamountaineer connector on that new topic.

Comment: Can u just send me the code for consumer as samples if u have any?

Comment: @SachinKademane which language ?? i can give u link

Comment: java... can u give

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ingest the data as-is into Kafka, and than use Kafka Streams and split each array into individual message via `flatMap()`. The result can than we exported to InfluxDB via Connect API.

Comment: Can u get me that kafka stream code for doing this..because i dont know how to use json in kafka streams since i m new to this?

Comment: I think if you are going to use a datamountaineer connector, u can't achieve this by using Kafka streams also because connector will directly pull messages from a topic.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with KSQL. For Kafka Streams, you can check out examples here: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples (SO is not a "please write my code service" ;))

Comment: @SHAKEELMOHAMMAD Not sure what you mean... Are you familiar with Kafka Streams? (-> https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/) It's a stream processing library and it can transform data.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax hmm k let me try with kafka streams...but does kafka stream has support for json?? if so what all packages i need to import?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax the way connector work is that it will directly pull data from Kafka topic and pushes to your downstream(data warehouse).

Comment: You first need to read the data with Kafka Streams, and write the transformed result back into a topic that you use to push to downstream data warehouse -- thus, the result topic must be in the format you need for exporting. Kafka Streams can work with any data format :)

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax can u give me a kafka stream code related to this topic ?